# Validate react-input-mask length using Formik + Yup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, formik, yup

I have a problem validating the length of the Tel No. in my React app. I need to validate the length that if it is less than the intended length, it should output the error.

[image: Edit Input-masking-material-ui-formik-react-input-mask]

```
let validateSchema = yup.object().shape({
  tel_no: yup
    .string()
    .test("len", "Invalid Tel No.", (val) => val.length === 14)
    .required("Tel No. is required")
});

const PhoneForm = () => {
  return (
    <Container style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          tel_no: ""
        }}
        validationSchema={validateSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 500);
        }}
      >
        {({
          errors,
          values,
          setFieldValue,
          isSubmitting,
          touched,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          handleChange
        }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <InputMask
              mask="99-999999999-9"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.tel_no}
            >
              {() => (
                <TextField
                  type="text"
                  label="Telephone Number (Ex: 56-452678899-8)"
                  name="tel_no"
                  fullWidth
                  variant="outlined"
                  helperText={touched.tel_no ? errors.tel_no : ""}
                  error={touched.tel_no && Boolean(errors.tel_no)}
                />
              )}
            </InputMask>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              disabled={isSubmitting}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `val` (in the function on `test` 3rd parameter) actually is considering the `-` and `_` from the `InputMask` component. So 1 way to solve this is just to replace those symbols when you perform the validations

```
let validateSchema = yup.object().shape({
  tel_no: yup
    .string()
    .test("len", "Invalid Tel No.", (val) => {
      const val_length_without_dashes = val.replace(/-|_/g, "").length;
      return val_length_without_dashes === 12;
    })
    .required("Tel No. is required")
});
```

[image: Edit Input-masking-material-ui-formik-react-input-mask (forked)]

Comment: Thank you. The "Tel No. is required is not appearing when it is empty? Is it possible that if it is blank, you output the required error message? You only output the "Invalid Tel No." when you begin typing or if it has a value already

Comment: I also notice that when you click the submit button immediately without typing anything. It doesnt output the error message unless you touch it.

Comment: if you open dev tools and look at the console, you will see `val` is `undefined` at that point (i.e., the scenario you are describing). so 1 solution for this is to simply assign a default value (an empty string) to `val`. e.g., `(val = "") => {` - hope this helps